# Auto reload chrome extension when files change in the extension folder

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How add a feature in chrome extension to automatically reload the chrome extension when there is any change in the file in that extension folder ?

Comment: Is this for dev purpose or for live extensions?

Comment: live extension.